# About embeddings of connected sums

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two soomth manifolds who're already embedded in $\mathbf{R}^k$.
Can one prove that the connected sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$ can also be embedded into  $\mathbf{R}^k$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See the [Manifold Atlas Project.](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/High_codimension_embeddings%3a_classification#Embedded_connected_sum)